# how do I "link against the Interception library"?

Tags: c++, libraries

I'm trying to follow the instructions for this project. 
http://www.oblita.com/interception.html

Never programmed in C or C++ before.

I've downloaded microsoft visual studio and build tools, and interception project, but when I try to build one of the samples it doesn't work. I think its because I don't know how to link the library.

at first I tried to include the files I downloaded. Then I tried to move the .h and library files into my visual studio library. either way I still get the same error.

Here's the code

```
#include ".\interception\library\interception.h"
#include ".\interception\Interception-master\samples\utils.h"

enum ScanCode
{
    SCANCODE_X   = 0x2D,
    SCANCODE_Y   = 0x15,
    SCANCODE_ESC = 0x01
};

int main()
{
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Here's an image of what I'm working with: (red indicates error) (blue indicates the file I'm working on)

[image]

So I guess I don't know how to do the 2nd step in the interception tutorial - Linking Libraries. How does one do that?

Comment: I've looked at the question this is marked as a duplicate of. It was no help. Are there any tutorials or rudimentary resources or lessons on this topic somewhere?

Comment: The dupe clearly explains how to link to third party libraries and your own stuff with MSVC. Read more carefully.